# regenerate iptables from "iptables -L"after disk failure

Tags: iptables, firewall, restore, 14.04

My system disk failed catastrophically. I've replaced and mostly restored the OS on a new disk but all I have for my iptables is the output from `iptables -L`.  Is there a way to automatically recreate the `rules.v4` from this text?  I've installed `iptables-persistent`.  This is the only iptables I've ever created.

TIA Nate

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate     RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:4960
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:4955:4956
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:4958
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp fragmentation-needed
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 10/sec burst 5
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain LOGNDROP (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min  burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "Denied TCP: "
LOG        udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "Denied UDP: "
LOG        icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "Denied ICMP: "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: See http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/iptables#Saving_your_configuration

Comment: Also , order of your rules is important. Your first rule appears to accept all traffic, so all the other rules are going to be ignored.

Comment: Also you should use REJECT not DROP 0- see http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~peterb/network/drop-vs-reject

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Thanks for the information.  I was able to find links to other tutorials that helped me create a better version (I think) than I had and save a copy of rules.v4 for a backup.